# How to merge two object of array lists in one array list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I'm trying to mix this objects which contain an array:

```
var a = {[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]};

var b = {[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]};
```

in one level array:

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
];
```

In JavaScript, I'm trying this without success:

```
var arr = a.concat(b);
```

because this gives me:

```
[
    {[
      {...},
      {...},
      {...}
    ]},
    {[
      {...},
      {...},
      {...}
    ]}
]
```

how can I obtain one level array?

Answer (score 4):

That's because `a` and `b` are not arrays. Assuming you can modify the json format (and you should as it's not valid) you could change it for this

```
var a = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
];

var b = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
];
```

Then your code would work just fine